# MultiPeerConnectivity programmatically

Tags: ios, swift5, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I am making an application that transfers data between phones. how can I connect and accept a connection request from another device programmatically without MCBrowserViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked in multipeer connectivity framework and I hope I am able to help you.

**Step 1:**

You can use MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser for advertising yourself with your custom service-type like:

```
let advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser.init(peer: *peerID*, discoveryInfo: *dict*, serviceType: *custom_service_type*)
```

set the delegate and start advertising yourself.

**Step 2:**

In other device , user MCNearbyServiceBrowser

```
let browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser.init(peer: *peerID*,serviceType: *custom_service_type*)
```

set the delegate and start browsing for peer users.

**Step 3:**

When the browser finds some users in the same Wi-fi network and with same service type, you will get a delegate callback to

```
func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?)
```

**Step 4:**

Manually try connecting to the peer

```
browser.invitePeer(*peerID*, to: *session*, withContext: nil, timeout: 30)
```

**Step 5:**

In the first device, you will get a callback in delegate method saying that a peer device wants to connect

```
func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void)
```

call the completion handler with a true value and share your session

```
invitationHandler(true,*session*)
```

Here we don't need any user interaction. All are done programmatically(which is your requirement).

**Note:**

1. The service type of both the advertiser and browser must be the same.
2. Make sure you confirm to the protocols(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate,MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate).
3. Make sure you have initialised a session properly before all these steps.

Comment: thank you so much. 
you helped me a lot. 

tell me more, have you worked with the method "session.sendResourceAtURL (url as URL, withName: filePath.lastPathComponent, toPeer: peer)"?

Comment: i make it
but i don't know how present progress status sending data

Comment: The "session.sendResourceAtURL (url as URL, withName: filePath.lastPathComponent, toPeer: peer)" will return you a Progress Object. You can have a reference to it and use a timer to continuously check for the progress of file transfer . For more information on Progress, you can refer **https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress**